# Unclear moment in output redirect

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files `text1` and `text2` in the `~/Documents` folder.
When I enter the command
`ls >listing` and then view the content of the `listing` file I can see

```
listing
text1
text2
```

Could you explain technically why `listing` is included? I thought that it takes the output of the `ls` command which would have only 2 lines, then creates the `listing` file and puts those 2 lines there. But apparently not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell creates 'listing' as soon as it parses your command line; it has to call `open(2)` to obtain a file descriptor to pass to the forked process for `ls`. Thus it's there by the time `ls` starts.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.